# Keyboard keeps covering textfields in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My problem is: When I'm scrolling a page with TextFormFields and click on one of them, the keyboard goes over them.
I have only one solution: increase the bottom padding so much that the field is no longer covered, but this makes the layout ugly because now I have a significant portion of the screen with nothing useful there.

The so acclaimed response to this is: "Use MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom"

But THIS DOESN'T WORK.

Setting resizeToAvoidBottomPadding to true in scaffold doesn't work.

Wrapping my widget with SingleChildScrollView doesn't work either.

This happens in both stances that I use it: Under a scaffold and under a showModalBottomSheet().
Is there any other solution to this?

Edit: If the code really makes any difference, here it is:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        title: widget.school != null ? 'a' : 'b',
        hasBackButton: true,
      ),
      body: BackgroundCard(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomTextFormField(
                      title: 'CNPJ:',
                      controller: _controllers[0],
                    ),
           ...
```

Here is the background card:

```dart
class BackgroundCard extends StatefulWidget {
  BackgroundCard({
    @required this.child,
    this.padding,
    this.bottomPadding = 0,
    this.filterAction,
    this.addAction,
    this.addTitle,
    this.tileCount = 0,
  });
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final double bottomPadding;
  final String addTitle;
  final VoidCallback addAction;
  final VoidCallback filterAction;
  final int tileCount;

  @override
  _BackgroundCardState createState() => _BackgroundCardState();
}

class _BackgroundCardState extends State<BackgroundCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool hasTopButton =
        widget.addAction != null || widget.filterAction != null ? true : false;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          16.0,
          24.0 - (hasTopButton ? 12 : 0),
          16.0,
          48.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                if (widget.filterAction != null)
                  OutlineButton(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: kYellow, width: 1.6),
                    onPressed: () => widget.filterAction(),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.search, color: kYellow),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                        Text(
                          'Filter',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .headline5
                              .apply(color: kYellow),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                Spacer(),
                if (widget.addAction != null)
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => widget.addAction(),
                    color: kYellow,
                    child: Text(
                      widget.addTitle ?? '',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .headline5
                          .apply(color: kWhite),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
            hasTopButton ? SizedBox(height: 12.0) : Container(),
            Container(
              padding: widget.padding ?? const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kWhite,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.16),
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: widget.child,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit2: So I figured that the problem most probably is related to a plugin I use: persistent_bottom_nav_bar. So I guess any answer here won't solve my problem. I will elegy some answer as the best though.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible code!!! Otherwise we can not help you

Comment: @LonelyWolf ok added it, if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to use the **reverse parameter** on whichever ListView you are working with.

In order not to start at the end of the form it is also useful to only make it reverse when the keyboard is up, for this I personally use the package *keyboard_visibility*.

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: MyForm(),
  ),
));

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  MyForm() : super();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}

class MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onChange: (bool visible) {
        if (!visible) {
          setState(() {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20, 20, 0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: isKeyboardVisible ? true : false,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i=0; i<100; i++) TextField()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you "pub get" ?

Comment: Here is the package, they show you how to get it and import it: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility

Comment: yeah i was adding the wrong package. This doesn't work anyway

Comment: Could you be more specific ? It works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. It seems related to viewInsets.bottom not updated (it is always 0 even if the keyboard shows).
This is my snippet:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _keyboardBottomInset = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    final _screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    print(
        "Bottom inset is -> $_keyboardBottomInset and height: $_screenHeight");

    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: TextFormField(
      initialValue: 'eventday',
      minLines: 20,
      maxLines: 20,
    )));
  }
```

The weird thing is that the same exact code works when I run it from an old project. The bug I opened is [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60348).